On working memory testing
I have a question regarding the testing for working memory. I am aware of 3 tests. The first is a matrix test, where you are shown multiple shaded squares for some time and asked to remember them. The second consists of showing a string of numbers all at the same time. The third is like the second, but the difference is that in the third test, one number is shown at a time, then it disappears and another number is shown, then the subject is asked to write the string of numbers that were shown.
I personally do well on the first and second tests. But I don't do as well on the third one. I can easily memorize a string of numbers if it were to be shown at an instant, instead of one number being shown at a time.
I assume from this that there are subsets of working memory, which are correlated with each other, just like the g factor.
Another test which I do well in, is pictures being shown one at a time, and you are asked not to remember the order the pictures were in, rather you are given a multiple choice question asking what pictures you saw.
I did some research into this, and I found that indeed some people do well on some working memory tests and not on others. I just wanted to ask whether it is safe to assume that working memory is a construct with many subtypes like the g-factor, where the subtypes are linked. A further question that comes up if the first assumption is true, is whether we can find a law of diminishing returns in WM like Spearman's law of diminishing returns in the g construct.
